# Как отрисовать текст поверх объектов которые генерируются на карту с помощью скрипта (Unity)?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, 2d

Это 2Д проект в Unity.

Текст отображается только в канвасе, а объекты поверх которых нужно отрисовывать текст находятся вне канваса.
Как отрисовать текст поверх объектов которые генерируются на карту с помощью скрипта ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Самый удобный вариант сделать еще один [Canvas](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-Canvas.html) и настроить его `RenderMode` на вывод в мировых координатах или координатах камеры. Только позицию для текста вам придется определять самостоятельно. Я бы установил `WorldSpace` и выставлял текст в нужную позицию поближе(через ось Z) чем объект для которого он рисуется, чтобы текст не перекрывался.

Answer (score 0):

Можно прибегнуть к способу, с использованием `Sorting Layer`.
Используйте слой отрисовки, чтобы отрисовать объект поверх других, данный слои нужны, для упорядочивания спрайтов, вместо использования координаты z.

Более подробно, можно узнать пройдя следующий урок по `Sorting Layer`:
http://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/sorting-layers

Или же прочесть следующий материал (мануал по тэгам и слоям отрисовки):
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно привязать к объекту (префабу) преднастроенный экземпляр Text 3D или его улучшенного аналога Text Mesh PRO (последнее - более красивое и гибкое).
Задать слой отображения "над" спрайтом.
Из плюсов - такой текст можно периодически "кидать" в разные стороны (отображая урон или событие вроде крита или промаха) и иметь на объекте не в единственном экземпляре (выстрел из дробовика - куча цифр разлетается облачком от поражённой цели) и его положение не нужно особо сильно считать.
Но надо действовать аккуратно, если планируете разместить толпу объектов, из которых может единовременно посыпаться много сообщений (например при паравоз-фарме со сплешовым уроном). Для последнего случая наверное лучше продумать какую-то хитрую систему частиц с "запеканием" значений урона в спрайты для передачи в эмиттер (или как-то так).

Простой вариант будет выглядеть примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]